# Add additional costs based on quantity in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem and I've looked everywhere to find a solution for it, but I can't find it.
I want to set up a webshop with Woocommerce, but I need the following function to make it work:

- My supplier calculates a packaging fee of 15$ for some of the products when these specific products get ordered in an odd quantity (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, etc). Since these products are packed in pairs of two, they herefor have to break open the package. That's why they calculate extra costs for this. However, this rule doesn't apply on all products.

I hope someone knows a solution for this. You would be my hero!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like that:

```
// Hook before adding fees 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

/**
 * Add custom fee on article specifics
 * @param WC_Cart $cart
 */
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
    $fees = 0;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        // Check if odds and if it's the right item
        if( $item[ 'quantity' ] % 2 == 1 && get_post_meta( $item[ 'product_id' ], 'custom_fee_for_supplier_name', true) ){
            // You can also put a custom price in each produt with get_post_meta
            $fees += 10;
        }
    }

    if( $fees != 0 ){
        // You can customize the descriptions here
        $cart->add_fee( 'Custom fee (odds paquets)', $fees);
    }

}
```

Then, you have to go on each product, on custom field box and click on `add a new custom field` 
name : custom_fee_for_supplier_name and 1 to activate the custom fee.
[image: Custom_fee]

Comment: The solution from XcID works fine, you can take that as the solution.