# Woocommerce - Extra fee based on product quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I found this answer in a earlier post here (below), but I want to know of there is any way to add an extra fee based on quantity if the product quantity changes?
Lets say there is 100 items in one package. (the problem is also that there is not they same amount of item in all packages, some can be 100, some can be 150, 200, or 500)
Example:
1-99 = 1$. 
100 = no fee. 
101 - 199 1$
200 = no fee
201 - 299 = 1$ and so on..
Total will always be 1$ per product but the total can be more if they order several products that have these breaks. The total can be 4$ if there is 4 products with break-cost.

(Also, not sure where to put the code)

Thank you!

The code I found here: [Add additional costs based on quantity in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171557/add-additional-costs-based-on-quantity-in-woocommerce#new-answer?newreg=b45d430bf4974e2dbdae6a2f1c34f421)

```
// Hook before adding fees 
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');

/**
 * Add custom fee on article specifics
* @param WC_Cart $cart
 */
function add_custom_fees( WC_Cart $cart ){
$fees = 0;

foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ){
    // Check if odds and if it's the right item
    if( $item[ 'quantity' ] % 2 == 1 && get_post_meta( $item[ 'product_id' ], 'custom_fee_for_supplier_name', true) ){
        // You can also put a custom price in each produt with get_post_meta
        $fees += 10;
    }
}

if( $fees != 0 ){
    // You can customize the descriptions here
    $cart->add_fee( 'Custom fee (odds paquets)', $fees);
}

}
```

Comment: It isn't a "fee" but [Dynamic Pricing](http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/) is suited to the type of complicated pricing rules you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` fires right after a quantity is updated. If you modify your function a little bit (to use `WC()->cart` to access the cart object) you can run the same function on both hooks. I thought it might keep adding additional fees, but in my testing it seems to just recalculate the right cost for the same fee.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'add_custom_fees');
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'add_custom_fees' );

/**
 * Add custom fee on article specifics
* @param WC_Cart $cart
 */
function add_custom_fees(){
    $fees = 0;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){ 
        // Check if odds and if it's the right item
        if( $item[ 'quantity' ] % 2 == 1 && get_post_meta( $item[ 'product_id' ], '_custom_fee_for_odds', true ) ){
            // You can also put a custom price in each produt with get_post_meta
            $fees += 10;
        }
    }

    if( $fees > 0 ){
        // You can customize the descriptions here
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Custom fee (odds paquets)', $fees);
    }

}
```